# Hp OMEN: Ubuntu 20.4 bluetooth adaptors not recognised

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04

I have hp omen laptop model: 15-dh0135TX, bluetooth toggle switch does not make any difference.
I searched online and did this, uninstalled blueman, reinstall blueman and ran blueman-manager, and this was the response `blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting
blueman-manager 21.51.56 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adaptor not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 21.51.56 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adaptor(s) found, exiting`

Please help, thanks in advance :)